# Bookmarks in nautilus only in menu, not in the shortcut tab

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

Bookmarks added to Nautilus using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> do not appear under "bookmarks" in the Nautilus windows -- but they can well be seen in the Bookmarks menu entry:

[image]

I tried to restart Nautilus and log out / log in, but the problem persists. Is this a bug, or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the nautilus configuration settings, Open a terminal and do this

```
nautilus -q
rm -r ~/.config/nautilus/ -v
rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus/
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/nautilus
```

Then start nautilus again. 
This should fix the problem.

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: @January can you check the updated answer now?

Comment: OK, now I can use Ctrl-D to add a bookmark and it appears in the tab on the left side, although the old bookmarks do not. Thanks! However, I cannot add a bookmark via drag and drop.

Comment: Did not fix mine

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to edit bookmarks by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and change the url of a bookmark that already exists (and if you want you can change the name too).

Then the new one that you wrote will appear and the one that you "**replace**" will be created by Ubuntu again. I think that this is an error too but you can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a new pc today and sure enough this issue raised itself again.

I found that the not-obvious trick to this is that when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to open the bookmarks manager pop-up, you type the new name for the bookmark (basically type over whatever one is showing in the pop-up) and put in (manually) the path where it is, **then**, instead of <kbd>Jump to</kbd>, <kbd>Remove</kbd> or <kbd>Close</kbd>

### you actually just press enter!

[image]

This adds the bookmark and you can now add another (or close the window).