# How can I add a bookmark in my nautilus folder explorer

Tags: nautilus, directory, filemanager, bookmarks

In Ubuntu 11 I just dragged the folder there.  This seems to be not possible on my new Samsung ultrabook with Ubuntu 12.04

[image]
I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and using the top menu but nothing happens and no error messages, just nothing.

How can I add a bookmark?

Comment: One can bookmark the current directory through the small menu icon at the top right corner next to the minimize window button. You can create a new directory, zoom in/out as well from the menu.

https://www.scivision.co/nautilus-ubuntu-add-bookmark-favorite/#comment-3893638049

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you can do is to edit bookmarks by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and change the url of a bookmark that already exists (and if you want you can change the name too). Then the new one that you wrote will appear and the one that you "replace" will be created by ubuntu again. I think that this is an error too but you can fix your problem

Answer (score 77):

Got same ergonomic problem!

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or Add Bookmark will function only when "desired link folder" is selected on Location Bar. "Bookmarks" will appear only on Places (Nautilus) after placing one bookmark. Not so friendly IMO...

References:
"Adding a Bookmark

To add a bookmark, open the folder or location that you want to bookmark, then choose Places->Add Bookmark.

If you are using a Nautilus browser window, choose Bookmarks->Add Bookmark."
From: http://linux.about.com/library/gnome/blgnome6n6p.htm

And
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2027355

And finally, Help from Ubuntu:
Ubuntu Desktop Guide » Files › Tips and questions » Edit folder bookmarks

This is almost duplicated from:
[Nautilus bookmarks do not appear at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/188102/nautilus-bookmarks-do-not-appear-at-all)
?

Comment: Files > Enter location and then Ctrl-D when the folder path edit box is displayed worked for me in 13.04

Answer (score 11):

Once you add your first bookmark using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, bookmarks will appear on the Nautilus tab and you will be able to use drag and drop. Seems to be a bug rather than a feature. However, I [had some problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184851/bookmarks-in-nautilus-only-in-menu-not-in-the-shortcut-tab) with that as well.

Comment: ctrl-D and Add Bookmark from the menu do not do anything.  No errors and no changes.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Did you try the solution presented in the linked question.  Are the bookmarks accessible though the menu?

Answer (score 8):

This issue is fixed with the new updates.

Now Bookmarking works smooth, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 18.04 is what I am using, I add this answer because it appears in google search but the solutions provided were not as intuitive. And this is the visual approach. CTRL+D does work but...

I normally drag the folder into the explorer menu on the left.
However this was not possible specifically with the root folder.

So I had to find the solution to the problem above, which was very simple once I found it.

Navigate to ROOT and then use the middle button (with plus symbol, above 100%) in this picture to create the bookmark, this would add the current folder to the left-hand folder explorer.

[image]

Comment: You're right about Ubuntu 18.04, we need to zoom about 100% to get bookmark option in left side. It is some kind of bug I think.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and then edit the directory!