# Nautilus bookmarks do not appear at all

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bookmarks in nautilus only in menu, not in the shortcut tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184851/bookmarks-in-nautilus-only-in-menu-not-in-the-shortcut-tab)

On my latest Ubuntu install, using version 12.04, my bookmarks are not there.

I can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to add bookmarks, but the bookmarks part of nautilus is missing altogether so they are not showing.

i.e. the sidebar panel doesn't have a bookmarks section.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best workaround has been to add a different File Manager from the Software Center (pcmanfm).

This doesn't have a bookmarks section but it *does* allow me to drop items into it as links.

Answer (score 2):

The bookmarks section will not be shown until you add a bookmark by either pressing **Ctrl-D** or dragging and dropping in the side bar.

Once you add a bookmark, A section will be created with **Bookmarks** name and will show your added folders.