# How to create a Directory, which can be accessible to all user and will be locate at Places like Desktop/Documents

Tags: permissions, mount, files, directory

I want to create a directory with all permission which Download/Document has. and I want to mount that directory to the Places where we can see the Desktop, Downloads ( Left Side Panel ), which will be accessible to all users not only root.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Create a directory `/home/shared` accessible to everyone:

```
sudo mkdir /home/shared
```

Change owner of the directory, assume name of the user is `alice`:

```
sudo chown -R alice:alice /home/shared
```

Change access rights with read-only access:

```
sudo chmod -R 744 /home/shared
```

or with read-execute access to everybody:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/shared
```

or with read-write access to everybody:

```
sudo chmod -R 766 /home/shared
```

or even make full-access directory including executable rights:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/shared
```

Next everyone can add a bookmark for the directory `/home/shared` to Nautilus by pressing `Ctrl+D`.
More about Nautilus bookmarks:

- [How can I add a bookmark in my nautilus folder explorer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/188083/how-can-i-add-a-bookmark-in-my-nautilus-folder-explorer)
- [Bookmarks in nautilus only in menu, not in the shortcut tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184851/bookmarks-in-nautilus-only-in-menu-not-in-the-shortcut-tab)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a concern, All my users are logging into the system through LDAP, so there is no particular user. I want to give access to the all users whoever will log into the system.

Is there any command to bookmark the directory , because i want to do this from ansible to multiple systems at once and its not possible for me to go to the systems and bookmark one by one