# Nautilus bookmarks not showing in "Places"

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks, places

I have set some bookmarks from Nautilus (Bookmarks / Add bookmark), and this get showed under Bookmarks menu, but doesn't show under "Places" menu.

Some idea?

Comment: Is your *View -> Sidebar* really set to *Places* not to *Tree*?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/184851/bookmarks-in-nautilus-only-in-menu-not-in-the-shortcut-tab

Answer (score 0):

Has the same problem with 12.10, tried dragging the directory i wanted to bookmark and it didn't work, until i read the help and found out that to add a folder as a book mark all you had to do is to open the folder/directory and click on the bookmark menu and then add bookmark.

```
Ctrl+D
```

Is the shortcut key for performing the same task.